# How to filter records by dateTime using firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, dart

In my firebase Realtime Database, every document saved has a datetime variable.

Example, `dateTime:"2021-04-11T17:32:50.833523"`

I have the following URL which fetches all documents. However, I now want to fetch only today's documents. I know that there are two options to achieving this. First one is to fetch all the documents from DB and then filter only today's records. Second option is to tweak the URL and put the filter while fetching records from the DB.

First I would like to know which approach yields faster results?
If it's the second approach, then I would like to know how to achieve it.

Here's the function I am using:

```
Future<void> fetchAllOrders() async {
    final url ='https://fhgi-92211.firebaseio.com/orders.json?auth=$authToken';
    }
```

Comment: It might seem that the second is faster but keep in mind while calculating speed you should minimize loops inside loops here we don't have that 1-fetch and outside it a loop to filter suppose first one is m time and second is n it will take the maximum of them while in the 2- fetch with if is still time m so O(m) so unlees the loop takes more time than fetch which i think it's not they are the same speed with that being said I prefer using the filter while fetching its much cleaner and your being on the safe side

Comment: How do I achieve this? I want to fetch all the records of today ( regardless of the time of day)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do an object datetime which includes year month day time  it will definitely solve a lot of complexity that way u could search for datetime.day

Comment: Please provide an example

Comment: Please provide your model

Comment: My model is called order which contains id, name and dateTime object.

Comment: Instead of your datetime to be string make :{ year :string, month:string, day:string, time:string}  and when u add a new datetime u add {//inside of it year, month etc} and to find search for datetime.day

Comment: datetime.day is going to give me records of same date even from previous month isn't it?

Comment: I suppose you are right then we should check day month and year to be equal to this day and this month and this year together

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, something like this should work:

`'https://fhgi-92211.firebaseio.com/orders.json?auth=$authToken&orderBy="dateTime"&startAt="2021-04-11"'`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data

Answer (score 0):

##### Best solution - is n°2 : using & tweaking your URL - to do so I suggest :

First, tweaking your model by adding your date data in a simpler `2021-04-11` kinda of format

It will allow you much easier filtering

You can do so like this before writing your data to your RealTime Database :

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateTime today = DateTime.now();
String simpleFormatToday = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(today);

// returns a simple 2021-04-11 format of today's date
```

*If your really need for some reason the full dateTime value you can **write** both `dateTime:"2021-04-11T17:32:50.833523"` & `simpleDate:"$simpleFormatToday"` to your object*

---

Next,

**To retrieve your data** - use your function & tweak your URL to use [Range Querying](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#range-queries) to retrieve only documents having *`simpleDate` value equal to today* - like so :

```
Future<void> fetchAllOrders() async {
    final url ='https://fhgi-92211.firebaseio.com/orders.json?auth=$authToken&orderBy="simpleDate"&equalTo="$simpleFormatToday"';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Approach** 
It will be useful if you want to get all the data and need to filter the dates several times from user input. 
*For example*: If you have 100 records that you fetched using first approach i.e all you have is 100 records in your db and now user will make some filter on fetched records like getting 20-30 then 40-79, something like that. In this case making query using second approach wont be appropriate because of two reasons

1. Querying everytime on firebase would count read/write towards billing.
2. Managing data locally is more fast and reliable rather than making request to network frequently.

**Second Approach** 
It will be useful in areas where you have to show specific time interval records in the one go and that's it, after fetching the records you dont need more of them to pull out from DB.

The Query will mainly revolve around what you want
*equalsTo* : It will give you only those records which will have exact date that you have passed as params.
*orderBy* : It will only work with equals to and will give you dates on bases of applied sorted filter (ex: by `createdAt`)

```
Future<void> fetchAllOrders() async {
  //It will get today's date
  var todaysDate = DateTime.now();
  //From today's 12AM
  var filterStartDate = DateTime(todaysDate.year,todaysDate.month,todaysDate.day,0,0,0);
  //To second days' 11:59PM
  var filterEndDate = DateTime(todaysDate.year,todaysDate.month,todaysDate.day,23,59,59);
  final url ='https://fhgi-92211.firebaseio.com/orders.json?auth=$authToken&startAt="${filterStartDate.toIso8601String()}&endAt="${filterEndDate.toIso8601String()}';
}
```